# I am receiving an undefined variable but my variables are defined while receiving main variable (myID) from another page

Tags: php, html

I keep getting an undefined variable error when my variable has been defined. I have tried multiple different suggestions from Stack Overflow but none of them are working for me. The purpose of this page is to edit content in a PHP table.

I have tried redefining my variable in different ways suggested on this website. For example, I've tried adding "mysql_fetch_object" for "myID". I also have tried using a new variable to define "myID" `($newID = mysql_fetch_object($myID))`.

```
<?php
// Server credentials
$servername = "***";
$username = "***";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "***";

// Creating mysql connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Checking mysql connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

// Writing a mysql query to retrieve data
// ERROR HERE
$myID = $_GET['Event_id'];


$sql = "SELECT Event_id, title, event_date, location, description, status FROM events WHERE Event_id = $myID";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//if ($result->num_rows == 1) {
// ERROR HERE
//if ($result) {
  // Show each data returned by mysql
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {




      if(isset($_POST['submitc'])) {
          changeform();
      } else{
          header('location: events.php');
      }

          function changeform(){
          $title= mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['title']);
          $event_date = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['event_date']);
          $location = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['location']);
          $description = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['description']);

         if(!empty($title)) {
             mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET title = '$title' WHERE Event_id = '$myID'");
         } else{

         }

          if(!empty($event_date)) {
              mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET event_date = '$event_date' WHERE Event_id = '$myID'");
          } else{

          }
          if(!empty($location)) {
              mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET location = '$location' WHERE Event_id = '$myID'");
          } else{

          }

          if(!empty($description)) {
              mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE events SET description = '$description' WHERE Event_id = '$myID'");
          } else{

          }
      }


?>

<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>I491 MakeUp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="eventcss.css">
</head>
<header>

    <div id="text">

<!-- script for header animation-->
    <script class="logo" type="text/javascript">
    var i=0, text;
    text = "I491 Make-Up"

    function typing(){
        if(i<text.length){
            document.getElementById("text").innerHTML += text.charAt(i);
            i++;
            setTimeout(typing,50);
        }
    }
    typing();
</script>
</div>

</header>

<body>

    <div class="edit_part">
    <form method="post" action="editevent.php">
    <p> Title: <?php echo $row["title"]; ?>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Title" name="title" value="<?php echo $title; ?>">
    </p>
<p> Date: <?php echo $row["event_date"]; ?>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Date" name="date" value="<?php echo $event_date; ?>">
</p>

<p> Location: <?php echo $row["location"]; ?>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Location" name="location" value="<?php echo $location; ?>">
</p>

<p>
Description: <?php echo $row["description"]; ?>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Description" name="description" value="<?php echo $description; ?>">
</p>

<button type="submit" name="submitc" value="1-or-anything">
     Submit Changes
 </button>
</form>

</div>

</body>


<?php
  }
 //}
//  else {
//   echo "0 results";
// }


// Closing mysql connection
$conn->close();
```

My expectation is to be able to change the PHP table to the input entered by the user by clicking the submit button. But also not changing the input if the user enters nothing.

Comment: I would take your MySQL credentials out of the example and change them, if those are your actual credentials anyway.

Comment: Also what page is submitting the `Event_id`? Could you share the code that is submitting it? I would also recommend sanitizing the input before running a database query with it by using the [mysql_real_escape_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) function

Comment: Do not use `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn`. Use prepared statements instead.

Comment: The page that is submitting the Event_id is my admin events page which displays the events in the database and has a button that leads admin to edit events.    

`<p> Title : <?php echo $row["title"]; ?> </p>`

`<p> Date: <?php echo $row["event_date"]?> </p>`

`<p> Location: <?php echo $row["location"]?> </p>`

`<p> Description: <?php echo $row["description"]?></p>`

`<p> Status: <?php echo $row["status"]?> </p>`

`<?php
     $myID = $row['Event_id'];
?>`

`<a href='editevent.php?Event_id=<?php echo $myID; ?>'>`

`<button name="edit_change" > Edit </button>`

Comment: Sorry for the format, my spacing edits keep defaulting back to what you see

Answer (score 0):

You're defining `function()`:

```
function changeform() {
    //  Your func body, where yo're using $myID now
}
```

Your function can't see variable `$myID` outside body. Functions can see variables, if variable was defined in function body:

```
funciton changeForm() {
    $myId = 1;
}
```

OR you are transmitting from another scope into function parameters:

```
$myId = 1;

function changeForm($myId) {
    $myId++;
}

changeForm($myId);
```

I recommend you to read the article about [variable scope](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: The OP left a comment where he is getting the error, and it is at the variable declaration, not in the function.

Comment: What's wrong with variable declaration? You mean, `$myID = $_GET['Event_id']` - is wrong, and after that definition we will get `Fatal Error`?

Comment: And that my friend, is why you ask clarifying questions before jumping to conclusions.

Comment: Variable declaration is fully true

Comment: @Jesse, This may well be due to the wrong index `$_GET['Event_id']`, but not with declaring.